FAIL: EvmError: Revert --> testFundUpdatesFundedDataStructure() (gas: 22067)
below is the code and i'm facing [FAIL: EvmError: Revert] testFundUpdatesFundedDataStructure() (gas: 22067) error. I HAVE EVEN ATTACHED GITHUB REPO TO THE CODE. GITHUB REPO
  function testFundUpdatesFundedDataStructure() public {
        vm.prank(USER); //the next transaction will be done by the user
        fundMe.fund{value: SEND_VALUE}();
        uint256 amountFunded = fundMe.getAddressToAmountFunded(USER); // Use USER here
        assertEq(amountFunded, SEND_VALUE);
    }


Inside the PriceConverter library, you've initiated the AggregatorV3Interface interface with this address 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306, which is deployed on sepolia testnet. Means you'll have to run the test on sepolia testnet (forking will work fine). Otherwise, forge will try to call the priceFeed in the local network, which will revert because 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306 doesn't exist locally.
I assume you were just running forge test, try running:
forge test --rpc-url https://eth-sepolia.public.blastapi.io
This will fork the sepolia testnet and run the test with the current state of sepolia testnet.
Another option is to create your own mock contract to test locally, without the need of forking.
